# Configure BFD OSPF (FRR 3.0.4)

Tags: network-interface, ospf

I installed an old version of FRR (v. 3.0.4) and can't figure out why ospf bfd is not working.
How to turn it on correctly? I couldn't find user guide documentation for old version of FRR.

Configuration:

```
SW1# show version 
FRRouting 3.0.4 ().
Copyright 1996-2005 Kunihiro Ishiguro, et al.
configured with:
     '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--host=arm-linux-gnueabi' '--prefix=/usr/' '--enable-user=root' '--enable-group=root' '--sbindir=/u'
SW1#
SW1# show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration:
!
frr version 3.0.4
frr defaults traditional
!
service integrated-vtysh-config
!
log file /var/tmp/frr.pipe
!
interface pv-0001
 ip ospf bfd
!
router ospf
 network 10.0.0.11/24 area 0.0.0.0
!
line vty
!
end
SW1#
```

I set `zlog_debug` for each **OSPF BFD** modules function, but it didn't help me figure out the reason.
**BFD** sends the **Zebra** event without error, but no **BFD** packets are sent across the interface after that.

I also observe that zlog_debug does not work in `ospf_bfd_init` (`ospf_bfd.с`). Could this be a sign that the **BFD** is not initialized?